# Configuring hibernate.reveng.xml to detect a sequence PK generator with hibernate3-maven-plugin and Postgre

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

is there a way to configure `hibernate3-maven-plugin` so that a sequence generator is detected for a `primary-key`? I'm using a bottom-up approach for `hibernate` configuration (which means letting `hibernate-tools` generate the hibernate configuration using a `jdbc-connection` for you via `reverse-engineering` on an existing database schema). I've read [this](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html), but also [this](http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-13693.html) already (those two can be unrelated, but can also leave a hint). My `hibernate.reveng.xml` is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering 
 SYSTEM "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <table name="ORDERS">
        <primary-key>
            <!-- setting up a specific id generator for a table -->
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">ORDERS_ORDER_ID_seq</param>
            </generator>
            <key-column name="ORDER_ID"/>
        </primary-key>
    </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

And I'm expecting it to generate an `Orders.hbm.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 2010-06-06 18:55:42 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.2.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="some.package.Orders" table="orders" schema="public">
        <id name="orderId" type="long">
            <column name="order_id" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">ORDERS_ORDER_ID_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
    ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

...but receiving this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 2010-06-06 18:55:42 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.2.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="some.package.Orders" table="orders" schema="public">
        <id name="orderId" type="long">
            <column name="order_id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
    ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I know my `hibernate.reveng.xml` is being read by `hibernate3-maven-plugin`, as I experience maven errors whenever syntax errors appear in the file, so `pom.xml` seems to be correct and `hibernate.reveng.xml` syntactically correct.

Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below the code that worked for me eventually. I just had to pass the `order` table name in lower-case (I used capital letters in my DDL so I actually don't understand, but this works). Also the `schema` attribute needs to be provided. The `<key-column name="pkey"/>` is optional (if you follow the hibernate naming convention).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering 
 SYSTEM "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <table name="orders" schema="public">
        <primary-key>
            <!-- setting up a specific id generator for a table -->
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">ORDERS_ORDER_ID_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </primary-key>
    </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Comment: This looks promising, but in my case Hibernate is ignoring the `table` tag and only processing `table-filter`. With the later Hibernate complains when the `primary-key` block is inserted.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try with **`<param name="table">...</param>`** (this is what I see in the [documentation](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/3.0/html/Hibernate_Tools_Reference_Guide/hibernaterevengxmlfile.html) or in [this thread](http://seamframework.org/Community/SeamgenrevengxmlSequenceEntryNotApplied)). So something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering 
 SYSTEM "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <table name="ORDERS">
        <primary-key>
            <!-- setting up a specific id generator for a table -->
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="table">ORDERS_ORDER_ID_seq</param>
            </generator>
            <key-column name="ORDER_ID"/>
        </primary-key>
    </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helped me finding the solution. The `name` attribute was not the problem, though. Both, i.e. `table` and `sequence` work fine depending on what you need. I updated my question with the code that worked for me.

Comment: @mmm: Well, not sure how my answer helped but... you're welcome :) Feel free to post your solution as answer and accept it (that's actually what you should do).

Comment: ok, added the solution as answer. Your answer helped by pointing to yet another discussion where I finally noticed the `schema` attribute might be missing :).